# Is there an efficient way of solving sparse linear equations in Tensorflow that is compatible with gradient tape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, tensorflow2.0

I need to solve equations in Tensorflow in the form A(y)x = b, where A is a large sparse band matrix and also a function of some other tensor say y. Naturally, the solution x will be a function of tensor y too. After solving for x, I want to take gradient of x with respect to y.

I considered two options:
1. Use a sparse external library to efficiently invert A, such as `scipy.sparse`. For this I need to convert the tensors to numpy array and then back to tensors. The problem with this approach is that I cannot use gradient tape with external libraries such as `scipy.sparse`.
2. Use Tensorflow's matrix inversion that works with gradient tape. This is extremely slow for large matrices, since it does not utilize the sparsity of the tensor. I was unable to find a sparse invert implementation in Tensorflow.

A small simplified example of what I need:

```
y = tf.constant(3.14)
A = my_sparse_tensor(shape=(1000, 1000)) # Arbitrary function that returns a sparse tensor
b = tf.ones(shape=(1000, 1))
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
  g.watch(y)
  A = A * y
  x = tf.matmul(sparse_invert(A), b)
dx_dy = g.gradient(x, y)
```

Of course the dependence of A on y is much more complicated than in this example.
Is there any way to do this in Tensorflow, or do I have to restrict myself to `tf.linalg.inv` ?